# Perform an action only for the chosen react children in a parent Component

Tags: reactjs, redux

In my react app I have a parent list component **Tests**:

```
 export class Items extends Component {

    static propTypes = {
        tests: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
        getItems: PropTypes.func.isRequired
    };

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.getItems();
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <Filters />
                {this.props.items.map((item) => (
                    <Item key={item.id} item={item} />
                ))}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    items: state.items.items
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItems })(Items);
```

**getItems** and **getItem** actions:

```
export const getItems = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get('/api/items/')
        .then(res => {
            dispatch({
                type: GET_ITEMS,
                payload: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    
export const getItem = (id) => dispatch => {
        axios.get(`/api/items/${id}`)
            .then(res => {
                dispatch({
                    type: GET_ITEM,
                    payload: id
                });
            })
            .catch(err => console.log(err))
```

and a children **Item** Component:

```
export class Item extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <div key={this.props.item.id} className="main"> 
               <p>{this.props.item.title}</p>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    items: state.items.items
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { getItem })(Item);
```

when you click on a **Item Component** for get it, the **Test** is re-rendered in map(). I get the result after the first execution of map(). But then **this.props.tests** get an empty array.
How do I handle onClick so the parent does not re-render all child components?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to add **bind()** to my method **getItem**:

```
onClick={this.props.getItem.bind(this, this.props.item.id)}
```

It works.